# Sharing thread to another class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, design-patterns

I have problem with designing multithread application for Android.

I have app which have two activity(MainActivity, LightActivity). I need to both of them communicate with server. I guess that I need another independent thread(IncomingThread) which handle communication from server to my activity, but don't know make it available for all two activities.

Now I've done this partial solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
private final byte[] ipNeuron = {(byte)192,(byte)168,(byte)1,(byte)129};
private final int port = 9876;
private boolean ListenerWorks = true;
byte[] bData = new byte[1024];
Thread IncomingThread;
DatagramSocket serverSocket;

final Handler myHandler =  new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        updateUI(msg.obj.toString());
    }

};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    ListenerWorks=true;


    IncomingThread =  new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            byte[] receiveData ;
            String sentence;
            DatagramPacket receivePacket;
            Message msg;
            serverSocket = null;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000); 
                serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                serverSocket.setSoTimeout(250);
                while (ListenerWorks) {

                    msg = myHandler.obtainMessage();
                    receiveData = new byte[1024];
                    receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
                    if (sentence.length()!=0){
                        msg.obj=sentence;
                        myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            serverSocket.close();
        }

    });
       IncomingThread.start();

}


private void updateUI(String msg){
    //handle msg and update UI      
}
```

}

```
public class LightActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_light);

    /*
    how to set up handler to obtain messages from IncommingThread?
    how to set up some pointer to IncommingThread?

    */          

}

private void updateUI(String msg){
//Update my UI 
}
```

}

Is it possible to access IncommingThread  from another activity(LightActivity)?
I know that one of solution can be set up services to handle the communication, but i thing it is much work like this way.

Comment: Service would throw NetworkOnMainThread exception if you do any network related task on it directly. Creating Threads manually as what you did works but I would strongly suggest you to use an IntentService, it should be a better approach to host a socket.

Comment: Matej, give a better description of why both of these activities need to share a thread.  Why can't they each perform their own http requests?  I think there might be some design issues that need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @MikeIsrael: I have application whitch send and receive UDP packets to server which controls another device. I have UI which I'm not able to fit in one screen(8x seekBar, 2xColorPicker and so on), so I had to split in two screens. I'm beginer in android, and I imagine that one screen=one activity. May be I have to design it like one activity with two screens but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: mockups of what you are trying to accomplish might help, but yeah two activities seems like overkill.  take a look at fragments for the two screen issue.